# How to implement Asynchronous calls in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I want to implement Asynchronous calls in WCF. All I want is to call Insert()  operation contract Asynchronously. This will insert records in History table. Since this is a time consuming process I want it to be done asynchronously. It has no return type.
Following is the code:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IDBService
 {

    [OperationContract]
    void Insert(RequestDetails Requestvalue);

    [OperationContract]
    void Update(RequestDetails Requestvalue);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
 }


  [DataContract]
  public class RequestDetails
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string messageType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string projectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string jsonMessage { get; set; }
  }


   public class DBService : IDBService
   {
    public string QueueDBConnectionString =   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueDBConnectionString"].ToString();
    DBConnection QueueDBConnectionObject ;
    public void Insert(RequestDetails Requestvalue)
    {
        QueueDBConnectionObject = new DBConnection(QueueDBConnectionString);
        QueueDBConnectionObject.Insert(Requestvalue);
    }

    public void Update(RequestDetails Requestvalue)
    {
        QueueDBConnectionObject = new DBConnection(QueueDBConnectionString);
        QueueDBConnectionObject.Update(Requestvalue);
    }
    }
```

Please help me to modify above code to work in an async manner.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is `DBConnection`? I only know `DbConnection` which has no `Insert` function

Comment: DBConnection is a class that I have written for data manipulation such as insert/update/delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, change your Contract to return Tasks

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IDBService
 {    
    [OperationContract]
    Task Insert(RequestDetails Requestvalue);

    [OperationContract]
    Task Update(RequestDetails Requestvalue);
 }
```

and that change the implementation as

```
public class DBService : IDBService
{
    public Task Insert(RequestDetails Requestvalue)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            QueueDBConnectionObject = new DBConnection(QueueDBConnectionString);
            QueueDBConnectionObject.Insert(Requestvalue);
        });
    }
 }
```

but this may not ne safe. I do not know the rest of your implementations and do not know the components you use.

Comment: Can you please specify why this piece of code may not be safe?

Comment: because i do not know the implementation of the rest of your class. `QueueDBConnectionObject` looks like it is assigned to often with a new instance: that may result in an error. but that looked dangerous before.

Comment: getting compile time error - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: fixed it. It is `Run` not `Start`!